# How do I check if a Perl scalar variable has been initialized?

Tags: perl

Is the following the best way to check if a scalar variable is initialized in Perl, using `defined`?

```
my $var;

if (cond) {
    $var = "string1";
}

# Is this the correct way?
if (defined $var) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Perl doesn't offer a way to check whether or not a variable has been initialized.

However, scalar variables that haven't been explicitly initialized with some value happen to have the value of `undef` by default. You are right about `defined` being the right way to check whether or not a variable has a value of `undef`.

There's several other ways tho. If you want to assign to the variable if it's `undef`, which your example code seems to indicate, you could, for example, use perl's defined-or operator:

```
$var //= 'a default value';
```

Comment: `//` and `//=` operators were introduced in Perl 5.10. For prior versions the `||` and `||=` operators do the same thing except they will overwrite an initialized "defined but false" value like `"0"` or `""`.

Comment: Begging your pardon, but scalars are `undef` by default, and the `defined` operator is what Perl offers to check against that value without incurring a "Use of uninitialized variable" warning.  ('Cause y'all do have `-w` and `use strict` in effect, right?)

Comment: Blrfl: That's right. That's your point though? A scalar having a value of undef is entirely unrelated to whether it has been initialized or not, considering perl can't at all distinguish between uninitialized scalars and scalars that happen to hold the value `undef` because someone set it to `undef`.

Comment: Blrfl: scalar *variables* are undef unless you assign them a value, but that doesn't mean that they are not undef if you do assign them a value.

Comment: **@Blrfl:** you can assign an `undef` value to a variable after it's been initialized.

Comment: @rafl and BDF: I guess my point is that if you're writing code that actively avoids using an undefined scalar in warning-inducing situations, the semantics of declaring that scalar without initiaizing them become that Perl initializes it to `undef` for you.  It may be splitting hairs, but I see assigning `undef` as effectively deinitializing the variable because its behavior becomes indistinguishable from Perl having done it for you.  (Hope that made sense...)

Answer (score 15):

It depends on what you're trying to do.  The proper `C` way to do things is to initialize variables when they are declared; however, `Perl is not C`, so one of the following may be what you want:

```
  1)   $var = "foo" unless defined $var;      # set default after the fact
  2)   $var = defined $var? $var : {...};     # ternary operation
  3)   {...} if !(defined $var);              # another way to write 1)
  4)   $var = $var || "foo";                  # set to $var unless it's falsy, in which case set to 'foo'
  5)   $var ||= "foo";                        # retain value of $var unless it's falsy, in which case set to 'foo' (same as previous line)
  6)   $var = $var // "foo";                  # set to $var unless it's undefined, in which case set to 'foo'
  7)   $var //= "foo";                        # 5.10+ ; retain value of $var unless it's undefined, in which case set to 'foo' (same as previous line)
```

C way of doing things (*not recommended*):

```
# initialize the variable to a default value during declaration
#   then test against that value when you want to see if it's been changed
my $var = "foo";
{...}
if ($var eq "foo"){
   ... # do something
} else {
   ... # do something else
}
```

Another long-winded way of doing this is to create a class and a flag when the variable's been changed, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care whether or not it's empty, it is. Otherwise you can check

```
if ( length( $str || '' )) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you plan on doing with the variable whether or not it is defined; as of Perl 5.10, you can do this (from [perl51000delta](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or_operator)):

> A new operator // (defined-or) has been implemented. The following expression:
>
> ```
>  $a // $b
> ```
>
> is merely equivalent to
>
> ```
> defined $a ? $a : $b
> ```
>
> and the statement
>
> ```
> $c //= $d;
> ```
>
> can now be used instead of
>
> ```
> $c = $d unless defined $c;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

'defined' will return true if a variable has a real value.

As an aside, in a hash, this can be true:

```
if(exists $h{$e} && !defined $h{$e})
```

Comment: `undef` is a real value. Using it as an indicator for "no value" is, while common, just a convention.

Comment: "real value" as in a valid scalar or reference value.

Comment: There is no such thing as an invalid scaler in perl.

Comment: Yes. You're speaking strictly, I was speaking conventionally.

Comment: +1 for I was wandering what the hell was happening here : 
$IniFile = "$ARGV[0]" ;
# perl defined or operator
# does not work perl -v (v5.12.3)
$IniFile //= "$ProductVersionDir/conf/$HostName/ini/run-$EnvironmentName.$HostName.ini";
# WORKS !
$IniFile = "/tmp/boo.ini" if ( "$ARGV[0]" eq "" )  ;