# How can I check if a value is undef in Perl?

Tags: perl, undefined-index

Best asked by an example:

```
my $var1=1;
my $var2;
my $var3=3;

# say "at least one undef" if at least one of $var1, $var2, $var3 is undef
```

Obviously I can explicitly loop and do that, but I always like to find one liners that achieve the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a Perl scalar variable has been initialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738836/how-do-i-check-if-a-perl-scalar-variable-has-been-initialized)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (grep { !defined } $var1, $var2, $var3) {
  say 'at least one undef'
}
```

one liner

```
say 'at least one undef' if grep { !defined } $var1, $var2, $var3;
```

Comment: `//` is a short-circuit operator, so it would be useful if you had a code path you want to execute conditionally based on the definedness of a single value. I can't think of a use here, but TMTOWTDI.

Comment: @David B, `//` is defined-or, so it can only be used to calculate "at least one defined".  To get "at least one undef", you'd need a defined-and operator, which doesn't (currently) exist.

Answer (score 1):

expanding on Bob's answer, in some cases, you might want to grab the actual count

```
say 'has ', scalar ( grep { not defined } $var1,$var2,$var3 ),' undef';
```